# Parse over large JSON array of Objects from Facebook

Tags: python

This is the JSON array:

```
{
  "id": "",
  "name": "",
  "posts": {
"data": [
  {
    "likes": {
      "data": [
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "QVFIUnpFd2IwMlhuOWI3dJqelFNNEZAPWDlqeENTNkg1N2RqMm9zQXBreVV6bE9KNXJzX29LeXlMZAzhNT2x3TEhlcGk3OG1Bd3ZABRmpyTXhnNDZAWV2hR",
          "after": "QVFIUl9Vbm14cld0dm41OTFtKYmgtelBKall2bnBINjBQMXBiNkNCMUM0d21lQXptOXRvbklkU0pHbV9yejNBVG9Jb2hqQTFoem1mdm9zMnJn"
        },
        "next": ""
      },
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 84,
        "can_like": true,
        "has_liked": false
      }
    },
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T18:22:19+0000",
          "message": "",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T18:51:24+0000",
          "message": "jfksjdkf",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-26T03:36:32+0000",
          "message": "ا",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T23:43:13+0000",
          "message": "",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T20:36:36+0000",
          "message": "kjlfkajsdlkafjowiuerjdsdflkjaslkdfjasdkfjoiuerksdjlkfjsadlkfjiasure",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T18:42:41+0000",
          "message": "jsfkasjdfkasjdflkjasdlkfjasd",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T17:51:12+0000",
          "message": "",
          "id": ""
        }
      ],
      "summary": {
        "order": "ranked",
        "total_count": 7,
        "can_comment": true
      }
    },
    "id": ""
  },
  {
    "likes": {
      "data": [
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "QVFIUl9aRjNZAcV92c2ZAPU1Y3bUhzVWI5em5uYVdDbnFMYURiMEF0QWxHYmJZAUzNEbkNZAX1o3R3VwbFFKOUFBcnA3dnl6WFZAmVTVn",
          "after": "QVFIUnJ3dDJvZAF9WTWNqk1SMmxiMk9qb3lna3FQQ0VGcU9wQ1p6b3EzMzdGZAV96NWJRV0k3R1U3M1NOaDdXRVRB"
        },
        "next": ""
      },
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 47,
        "can_like": true,
        "has_liked": false
      }
    },
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T17:45:47+0000",
          "message": "ajkdsfksjdfkljskfdjlker",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T16:33:31+0000",
          "message": "sfjgklsjktjekrjt",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T16:17:51+0000",
          "message": "",
          "id": ""
        },
        {
          "created_time": "2022-05-25T16:16:44+0000",
          "message": "",
          "id": ""
        }
      ],
      "summary": {
        "order": "ranked",
        "total_count": 4,
        "can_comment": true
      }
    },
    "id": ""
  }
],
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "before": "QVFIUnI4NUFnOGUtSFRnM3lGTTNLWURQQlNnUWlaU1FBdlFwZAlBybXAtTjNNTV9ENUhuRFhLYV9nR2lyZAkVHSVphN09IaTZAFLUctcVpLREtJZAkc0ZAjZAjY0xPWWZbncwUnlrQ2M5ZA09fenlmUVpuSGlCWk41a2ljZATJGMHkwYi1kQndIV0c4bm8yejVub29CNWF3bQZDZD",
    "after": "QVFIUkttZAWVDOGNLanBMUzVNSUtfaWRwREQtUzlGUlY0S1hjNFVoRVpFbE1Gc3I1c0pVc3NWZAG1NYlNZASll5empicHhKaUtqZAlM4ampDeU1Hd2VLZVjRVRld4N2pndkNlY0R5ZAGW5rNmpRNlAwWjdXRQZDZD"
  },
  "next": ""
   }
  }
}
```

I want to get the summary (total_count) from both the likes and the comments and the messages as well. So i decided to loop over them and store them as a tuple. The code is as follow:
Code:

```
import json
import requests 
import facebook 
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="")
profile = graph.get_object(id='me', fields='id,name,posts.limit(10) 
{likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)}')
x = json.dumps(profile, indent=4)
# print (x)


raw_data = json.loads(x) # parse the string into a python dictionary

useful_data = raw_data['posts']['data'] # Only picking concerned fields

output = {'day' : []} # This is where we will store the results as tuples of (value, end_time)

for el in useful_data:
    # if el['period'] == 'day':
    #     for i in el['values']: # Get all items in the values array
    #         output['day'].append( (i['value'], i['end_time']) )

    for i in el['likes']:
        for j in i['summary']:
            output['day'].append( (j['total_count']) )

print(output)
```

No matter what approach I take I always get the error (string indices must be integers). I even used JSON editor to better understand the JSON data but I still can't grasp what's going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @j1-lee basically I want a tuple like (messages, like_total_count, comment_total_count), after that I can loop over them and post through API.

Comment: @j1-lee    {'day': [('this is for message', '54','67'),....]   first field is the message, next field is the likes total_count and comment total_count. Does this help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No matter what approach I take I always get the error (string indices must be integers)

```py
    for i in el['likes']:
        for j in i['summary']:
            output['day'].append( (j['total_count']) )
```

should be

```py
    output['day'].append( el['likes']['summary']['total_count'] )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Honestly I feel like an idiot.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it happens with everyone